# unable to delete RDS DBs on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I'm not able to delete a database on RDS.

Deletion protection is not enabled, as per the following screenshot:

[image]

Despite that the "Delete" option on the menu is grayed out:

[image]

I've tried it with and without the DB being started and I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are selecting the cluster.

Delete "demo" not "demo-cluster".

Comment: Yup, you have to delete "demo" then you can delete "demo-cluster" ... just went through this. I think they changed it though, I got a prompt this time. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for sharing and for the upvote!